# Aws lambda failing while returning large data

Tags: c#, asp.net, aws-lambda

I am trying to export a data returned from lambda to csv format.For small data the code is working fine.But for larger data ,say 50000 records the service is throwing 502 - bad gateway error.

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(ResponseObj.ResponseStream);
return File(stream, "application/octet-stream");
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a 6Mb limit for request/response. Most likely you hit it. [Documentation link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html)

Comment: Is there any technique to tackle this issue. Like sending part by part ?

Comment: @Sharon yes. Alternatively I think you can save in S3 and return a link to get that data from S3 to caller.

Comment: My another requirement is to create an api to upload  file, as part of same request I have to do run a stored proc.I am using lambda to do this operation sequentially. Here i cannot upload the file directly to s3, instead i have to do it programatically. :-(

Comment: It depends on requirements, but maybe you can use pre-signed POST request to upload files to S3 directly from browser